# typescript - detect if function exists on a type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing `mocha` tests.

I have 2 interfaces(`TestInterface1, TestInterface2`). They have functions described on it such as:

- `TestInterface1` - `Func1, Func2`
- `TestInterface2` - `Func1, Func2, Func3`

In my tests, I have a class `Test` that sometimes ends up to be of `TestInterface1` but might still have a function `Func3`. It's like in run-time, can't decide which interface it belongs to.

Let's say it ended up to be `TestInterface1`. Now, it still could have `Func3`, but because of the interface, when I call function, it says that Function doesn't exist even though it does.  How can I still figure out that `Func3` still exists on the `Test` which is of `TestInterface1` ?

Comment: You can use type guards, `if ('Func3' in test) { /* test will now be of type TestInterface2 */ }`

Comment: Just for reference, the type guard enables TS to automatically perform [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Comment: IMHO I think that reveals a poor design and your problem is not that you can end up with different objects, is that your interface design is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
// ------
// stub declaration - you have defined those interfaces already
interface TestInterface1 {
  Func1: Function
  Func2: Function
}

interface TestInterface2 {
  Func1: Function
  Func2: Function
  Func3: Function
}

// assuming you have value already
declare const yourInterface: TestInterface1 | TestInterface2;
// ------

// and the IMPORTANT PART:
if ("Func3" in yourInterface) {
    // in this block, yourInterface is coerced to TestInterface2
} else {
    // coerced to TestInterface1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If (as stated in your question) you have already narrowed the type of the instance to be `TestInterface1`, then you'll need to assert that the `Func3` property is a function type in order to use it, because the compiler doesn't know it exists.

You can do this using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), like in the commented example below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAECEFMGMEMFcDOlQE8D29QBMCW2A7AcgBdRF4AHSgG1VBIAsUTVKV0AzNTAJ1E7wC0ErnQEANACgQoAJJEaNUJV7oAbvhSwGkALa1YJFJ3T8dAc0gFIvXNFDiUzXpABcU1u1AAxAgB4pUFAABVheWD1EUEgAD2MCbGjXWGxxOlAhAGsCdAB3AgBtAF1QAF5QWAJUEulggCVIChoyCqrUaQA+ctAACgA6QcpwyMQ3UJGogEpy7sbmkgBuKSlcAmNeTlhoFAAVJpI5ddstnYBGUABvIN8haDPxv2XgnzuAJkeCZYBfFbWN057A5HAHbSBvGLxaxJUD7RCHY6bMEXa4vO4AZk+PxWgmEonEoEYsEQr2E6NA-l2kISMLhCNB506vTW8KqO3Guym4xZJDZKFw0SpADJQvYspTgYjAW8JKAiKToOiiN1UaBXCR4LwCAw2JAuH0eXzKtF2lN+gryWUrXLcSIxMRsTIwABNPigACO8AO9vIvOM0SYRgYzFAhuE-JNNBS2HoBHCajykGwDHQsMlDMgDyk2BgNHCKGg4nhoYIrPDHPTJ2RyydoAAorF2CIkzFeGpeB4wztzRjelNFqBgAAqG7BMfBAB6U6nUhCanYvFYcotRBw6CaoFyZDiArIBK8KCIdJBVfORH6oAAIvgeFg9JAqsu7mciAB+XpvACsn7OMyHwBWWQAFVkGDFhdRUVw8DgYxO24XoiRJXsu0gKYZlVFCezJPsB1kdAsikb4gA)

```ts
// Because you didn't supply the type of your function,
// I'll provide a template for a generic one here:
type Fn<
  Params extends readonly unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...params: Params) => Result;

interface TestInterface1 {
  Func1: Fn;
  Func2: Fn;
}

interface TestInterface2 extends TestInterface1 {
  Func3: Fn;
}

function hasFunc3 <T extends TestInterface1>(instance: T): instance is T & Pick<TestInterface2, 'Func3'> {
  return typeof (instance as any).Func3 === 'function';
}

// Your question states that the instance is already narrowed to TestInterface1:
declare const instance: TestInterface1;

// Expected error:
instance.Func3(); /*
         ^^^^^
Property 'Func3' does not exist on type 'TestInterface1'. Did you mean 'Func1'?(2551) */

// Use the type predicate:
if (hasFunc3(instance)) {
  instance.Func3(); // ok
}
```